# Laravel config usage

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a config test.php

```
return [
    'name' => 'Testname',
    'street' => 'Teststraße',
    'street_number' => '69',
    'zip' => '42077',
    'city' => 'Winterfell',
    'telephone' => '0123456789',
    'email' => 'hsw@hsw.hsw'
];
```

created a ConfigServiceProvider:

```
    public function register()
    {
        config([
           'config/test.php'
        ]);
    }
```

but in my test.blade.php I can access the contents only via

```
{{config('test.0.name')}}
```

There has got to be a better, easier way for this right? The data is supposed to be used in multiple blades. Yet the ".0." feels so unnecessary.

I am new to PHP and Laravel, and I am using PHP 8.1 and Laravel 9.14.

Thanks in advance!

#######################

Edit: In my case I had the problem, that my cache wasn't cleared "php artisan config:cache" thanks to @matheenulla for hinting at that!. Thats why I tried the route with the ServiceProvider. I hope this may help someone in the future!

Comment: How about removing the `[]` in `config([...]);`

Comment: @NigelRen same result, i would need the ".0."

Comment: Are you getting any error if you use {{config('test.name')}} ?. You should use {{config('test.name')}} to get the result. Make sure you have clear cache  php artisan config:cache

Comment: no, its just empty, null okay, i didnt clear my cache, thanks @matheenulla

Comment: mostly it will work. you’re welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a service provider to use your config, unless you want it to be in some other location (in case you are creating a custom [Laravel package](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages)), so you may delete your `ConfigServiceProvider`. In fact, you're just using config wrong:

```php
{{config('test.0.name')}}
```

should be:

```php
{{config('test.name')}}
```

Comment: so my structure goes like project/config and project/resources/view and stuff.
When i go like {{config('test.name')}} and delete the provide, it doesn't show anything.
edit: needed my cache to be cleared, thats why it didnt work